# Group By 2 Columns and Find Percentage of Group In SQL

Tags: sql, percentage

I have a `Game` table with two columns `TeamZeroScore` and `TeamOneScore`. I would like to calculate the % of games that end with each score variance. The max score one team can have is 5.

I have got the following code which selects each team score with an additional 2 columns to have the max and min of these two values in order. I did this because I thought the next step is to group by these two columns

```
SELECT TOP (100000) [TeamOneScore],[TeamZeroScore],
  (SELECT Max(v) 
FROM (VALUES ([TeamOneScore]), ([TeamZeroScore])) AS value(v)) as [MaxScore],
  (SELECT Min(v) 
FROM (VALUES ([TeamOneScore]), ([TeamZeroScore])) AS value(v)) as [MinScore]
FROM [Database].[dbo].[Game]
```

Below is the sample data I have for the code above.

[image]

How do I produce something similar to this? I think I need to `Group By MaxScore, MinScore` and then use `Count` on each group to calculate the percentage based on the total.

[image]

Comment: I can't follow the second image, 1=>0 is Max=>Min?

Comment: The second image is just MaxScore and MinScore. Probably should have named them the same as the SQL

Comment: if you want the variance you can just use `abs(teamzeroscore-teamonescore)` and group on that, no need to bother with figuring out which score is greater

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Select
  Count(*) as "number",
  (100 * count(*)) / t
    As "percentage",
  TeamOneScore as score,
  TeamTwoScore as score
From
( Select
    TeamOneScore,TeamTwoScore
  From tablename
  Where TeamOneScore <= TeamTwoScore
Union all
  Select
    TeamTwoScore,TeamOneScore
  from tablename
  Where TeamOneScore > TeamTwoScore
) a,
(Select count(*) as t
 From tablename) b
Group by
  TeamOneScore,
  TeamTwoScore
Order by
  TeamOneScore,
  TeamTwoScore;
```

Comment: this is the right idea but only gives count rather than percentage

Comment: @Kurt thank you:  Modified. NB are there never games where the loser scores more than 1?